# Using iText 7 in java,how could i write data in two different column

Tags: java, itext7

I have two user objects in java with data id, name, surname, middle name, country, zone, district etc. and I want to write their data to a pdf(iText7 pdf) file in two separate column. Any advice!

My code is :

**User Class:**

```
private int id ;
private String name ;
private String middleName;
private String surname ;
private String email;
private String country;
private String zone;
private String district;
private String city;
private String tole;
private int zip_code;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getZone() {
    return zone;
}
public void setZone(String zone) {
    this.zone = zone;
}
public String getDistrict() {
    return district;
}
public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getTole() {
    return tole;
}
public void setTole(String tole) {
    this.tole = tole;
}
public int getZip_code() {
    return zip_code;
}
public void setZip_code(int zip_code) {
    this.zip_code = zip_code;
}
```

**JptTut Class**

```
public static final String DEST = "result/jpt.pdf";

public void createPdf(List<User> users) throws IOException{

      int i = 0;

      File file = new File(DEST);
      file.getParentFile().mkdir();

      PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));

      PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;
      float topBottom = 100;
      float offset = 20;
      float margin = 10;
      int colWidth = (int) ((ps.getWidth()-2*offset-2*margin)/3);
      int colHeight = (int) (ps.getHeight()-2*topBottom);

      PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(ps);
      PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

      Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(20,topBottom,colWidth,colHeight);
      Rectangle rectangle2 = new     Rectangle(208,topBottom,colWidth,colHeight);
      Rectangle rectangle3 = new   Rectangle(396,topBottom,colWidth,colHeight);

      pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle1);
      pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle2);
      pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle3);

      Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle1);
      Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(pdfCanvas,pdf,rectangle2);
      Canvas canvas3 = new Canvas(pdfCanvas,pdf,rectangle3);

      Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Details").setFontColor(Color.BLUE).setFontSize(20);
      Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("User ID :");
      Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("User Name :");
      Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("Surname :");
      Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph("Middle Name :");
      Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph("Email :");
      Paragraph p7 = new Paragraph("Country :");
      Paragraph p8 = new Paragraph("Zone :");
      Paragraph p9 = new Paragraph("District :");
      Paragraph p10 = new Paragraph("City :");
      Paragraph p11 = new Paragraph("Tole :");
      Paragraph p12 = new Paragraph("Zip Code :");

    canvas1.add(p1).add(p2).add(p3).add(p4).add(p5).add(p6).add(p7).add(p8).add(p9).add(p10).add(p11).add(p12);

for(User user:users){  

         if(i==0){
              Paragraph para0 = new Paragraph("To ").setFontColor(Color.GREEN).setFontSize(20);
              Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(user.getId()));
              Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph(user.getName());
              Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph(user.getSurname());
              Paragraph para4 = new Paragraph(user.getMiddleName());
              Paragraph para5 = new Paragraph(user.getEmail());
              Paragraph para6 = new Paragraph(user.getCountry());
              Paragraph para7 = new Paragraph(user.getZone());
              Paragraph para8 = new Paragraph(user.getDistrict());
              Paragraph para9 = new Paragraph(user.getCity());
              Paragraph para10 = new Paragraph(user.getTole());
              Paragraph para11 = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(user.getZip_code()));

         canvas2.add(para0).add(para1).add(para2).add(para3).add(para4).add(para5).add(para6).add(para7).add(para8).add(para9).add(para10).add(para11);
              i++;
         }
         else{

             Paragraph para0 = new Paragraph("From ").setFontColor(Color.MAGENTA).setFontSize(20);
              Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(user.getId()));
              Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph(user.getName());
              Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph(user.getSurname());
              Paragraph para4 = new Paragraph(user.getMiddleName());
              Paragraph para5 = new Paragraph(user.getEmail());
              Paragraph para6 = new Paragraph(user.getCountry());
              Paragraph para7 = new Paragraph(user.getZone());
              Paragraph para8 = new Paragraph(user.getDistrict());
              Paragraph para9 = new Paragraph(user.getCity());
              Paragraph para10 = new Paragraph(user.getTole());
              Paragraph para11 = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(user.getZip_code()));

        canvas3.add(para0).add(para1).add(para2).add(para3).add(para4).add(para5).add(para6).add(para7).add(para8).add(para9).add(para10).add(para11);

         }
      }


      pdf.close();    

}
```

}

**TestClass**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setId(1);
    user1.setName("Kamal");
    user1.setSurname("Rana");
    user1.setMiddleName("Magar");
    user1.setEmail("ranakamal@gmail.com");
    user1.setCountry("Nepal");
    user1.setZone("Bagmati");
    user1.setDistrict("Kathmandu");
    user1.setCity("Patan");
    user1.setTole("kumaripati");
    user1.setZip_code(234);

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setId(2);
    user2.setName("Santosh");
    user2.setSurname("Shrestha");
    user2.setMiddleName("Kumar");
    user2.setEmail("kumarsantos@gmail.com");
    user2.setCountry("Nepal");
    user2.setZone("Lumbini");
    user2.setDistrict("Nawalparasi");
    user2.setCity("Pragatinagar");
    user2.setTole("Bagwati Tole");
    user2.setZip_code(432);

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(user1);
    users.add(user2);

    new JptTut().createPdf(users);

}
```

}

Comment: Show what you tried. Ask specific questions, not just "Any advice".

Comment: I don't down-vote people with a reputation of 1, but this question really deserves the down-votes it received. Rohit should read the [iText: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial and try the examples, for instance the examples from chapter 7 dealing with tables.

Comment: Your code looks as if it should work, but why would you do it that way? As soon as one property of a user doesn't fit on one line, your layout will be wrong. Also: now you've shared a lot of code, but what is the problem? Can you explain what goes wrong?

Comment: I don't know the better way of writing code to achieve my goals.I am totally beginner in pdf file and of course in iText.I am doing a project in which i want to print the two user data without using table in two column with header and footer in a single page.I did this code in my own way but I think there is better way to achieve this.....so please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not specific enough, but allow me to make some guesses.

I have created an example named [KeyValueTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-tables-and-fonts#2832-keyvaluetable.java) that writes data from a user object to PDF in two columns. The result looks like this:

[image]

You say *I have two user objects in java with data id, name,...*

I assume that the class for such a user object is a POJO like this:

```
class UserObject {

    protected String name;
    protected String id;
    protected int reputation;
    protected String jobtitle;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getReputation() {
        return reputation;
    }

    public void setReputation(int reputation) {
        this.reputation = reputation;
    }

    public String getJobtitle() {
        return jobtitle;
    }

    public void setJobtitle(String jobtitle) {
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
    }
}
```

You say you have two of these objects, for instance:

```
UserObject rohit = new UserObject();
rohit.setName("Rohit");
rohit.setId("6633429");
rohit.setReputation(1);
rohit.setJobtitle("Copy/paste artist");

UserObject bruno = new UserObject();
bruno.setName("Bruno Lowagie");
bruno.setId("1622493");
bruno.setReputation(42690);
bruno.setJobtitle("Java Rockstar");
```

Then you say *I want to write their data to a PDF in two separate column.* I assume that you want to create a table, with the key in one column and the corresponding value in another column. That's easy, you have to create a `Table` as described in [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial:

```
public Table createTable(UserObject user) {
    Table table = new Table(2);
    table.setWidthPercent(30).setMarginBottom(10);
    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Key"));
    table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Value"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Name"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(regular).add(user.getName()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Id"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(regular).add(user.getId()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Reputation"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(regular).add(String.valueOf(user.getReputation())));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(bold).add("Job title"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setFont(regular).add(user.getJobtitle()));
    return table;
}
```

Now that we have a method that converts a `UserObject` to a `Table`, we can use that method to render these user objects to PDF:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
document.add(createTable(rohit));
document.add(createTable(bruno));
document.close();
```

It's that simple. Why did you ask? Was there something that wasn't clear in the documentation? What was your problem?

Of course: maybe you want the user data of `rohit` and `bruno` next to each other. That's explained in the second chapter of the tutorial. In any case: fix your question; read the documentation.

**Update:**

It seems that you are creating three columns. In the first column, you add keywords, in the second and third column you add the values corresponding with these keywords. You count on the fact that none of the data will take more than one line in its column. That is not a safe bet. Maybe it's OK for now, but you can't predict what will be needed in the future.

I have adapted my example; see [KeyValueTable2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-tables-and-fonts#2833-keyvaluetable2.java). The data is now rendered like this:

[image]

The `createTable()` method now looks like this:

```
public Table createTable(UserObject user1, UserObject user2) {
    if (user1 == null) user1 = new UserObject();
    if (user2 == null) user2 = new UserObject();
    Table table = new Table(3);
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(bold).add("Name:"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user1.getName()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user2.getName()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(bold).add("Id:"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user1.getId()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user2.getId()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(bold).add("Reputation:"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(String.valueOf(user1.getReputation())));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(String.valueOf(user2.getReputation())));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(bold).add("Job title:"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user1.getJobtitle()));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(regular).add(user2.getJobtitle()));
    return table;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
document.add(createTable(rohit, bruno));
```

I think that's what you want to achieve, and I'm pretty sure that the `Table` class is much better suited for your needs than what you've been trying so far.

Comment: Actually i have a User class as

Comment: @Rohit I've updated my answer. I've seen your code and while it may work (you didn't say what's wrong with it), I didn't like your approach. Using a `Table` for this kind of work is much better.